# Is juice as healthy as the veggies it comes from?

Tags: health, children, juice, vegetables

My little girl hates eating veggies, but loves the juice (like 100% carrot juice, “Superfood”, or V8). She is only 9, and I was the same way until I was around 20. So is there anything wrong with letting her have the juice rather than fight with about eating them? I still put them on her plate, and I still remind her that it’s the same stuff (this may be why she told me the juice was the same so it must be ok. Lol). So is the juice the same?

(Note that I am not asking about my parenting, I am asking about the juice being healthy for her.)

Thank you

Comment: Hi @KnotHeather, nutrition topics unrelated to exercise according to our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **IS** healthy **IF** the juice is made of real, natural veggies and not commercial products in general.

If you blend the veggie yourself, while keeping the **veggie skin**(since it contains most of vitamins,nutritents and fibre) then the juice will have the same effect as eating the raw veggies.